# i want to fetch value like 52,100 but it returns only52 mysql codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

comma separated by value fetch from the database

```
 public function get_data() 
     {  $this->db->select_sum("total_sale");
        $this->db->from('one_month_report');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
        } else {
        return FALSE;
       }
    }
```

Controller From Comment

```
public function profit_in_last_month_view() {

$this->load->view('pages/header'); 

$data['listProduct'] = $this->mproduct->get_data(); 

$this->load->view('pages/profit_in_last_month', $data); 

echo $this->db->last_query();

exit; 

$this->load->view('pages/footer'); 

}
```

Comment: provide sample data and explain proper what do you want

Comment: example: 20,2000 i want to fetch 20,2000

Comment: print last query and check the query

Comment: how to print last query thanks in advance

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query();exit;

Comment: please help it's return blank

Comment: Use this print query code after, in your controller where your are calling get_data() function.

Comment: @user6171329 after this `$query = $this->db->get();` **echo $this->db->last_query();exit;**

Comment: @user6171329 how `,` is in query?

Comment: This id my controller but not works public function profit_in_last_month_view() {
        $this->load->view('pages/header');
        $data['listProduct'] = $this->mproduct->get_data();
        
        $this->load->view('pages/profit_in_last_month', $data);
        echo  $this->db->last_query();exit;

$this->load->view('pages/footer');
    }

Comment: still it is showing result before comma  result in mysql

Comment: just like 20,512 it return only 20

Comment: but i want fetch 20,512 sum of number

Comment: please save my time and me , stuck from yestarday

Comment: @user6171329 `print_r($data['listProduct'])` and post the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should return the sum of total_sale of the most recent 52000 results.

---

```
$this->mproduct->get_data(52000)


public function get_data($limit,$offset=0){
  $limit = ($limit) ? $limit : 20;

  $q = $this->db
            ->select_sum('total_sale')
            ->limit($limit, $offset)
            ->order_by('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get('one_month_report');

  return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : null;
}
```

Comment: sorry it works but can't return all the value from db

Comment: it should just return the **sum** of **total_sale** not the actual results.